# will the watcher be set if async operation returns error with zookeeper client?

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper

i'm using zookeeper c api like this, i call async get and set watch on it:

```
zoo_awget(zhandle_, path.c_str(), true, watch_ctx, GetNodeDataCompletion, watch_ctx);
void GetNodeDataCompletion(int rc, const char* value, int value_len,
    const struct Stat* stat, const void* data) {
}
```

my question is: if the GetNodeDataCompletion's rc is ZOPERATIONTIMEOUT or some other errors, does the zookeeper lib guarantee that the watcher wont't be called after that even if zookeeper server may have received the watch request(for example, this is just a client timeout).

thanks.

Comment: i read the source of zookeeper client, and i find that there's no so-called client-timeout at all, so this is not a problem anymore.